# no predefined role when I copy postgres from one computer to another (both are windows OS)

Tags: windows, postgresql

I copied postgres from one windows computer to another (also windows) and start postgres on the latter one as a service (where "C:/PostgreSQL/data" is a new directory to store data), with the following command

```
pg_ctl.exe register -N PostgreSQL -D "C:/PostgreSQL/data" –S auto
```

But when I tried to create a server with username "postgres" it replies me that user postgres does not exist

I tried to connect to postgres or create a user by the following command (my username under windows is cdeguide), but I had no successs. Could you give me a way to create a postgres role

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin>psql -U postgres

psql: error: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

 

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin>psql

psql: error: FATAL:  role "cdeguide" does not exist

 

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin>psql -U root

psql: error: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

 

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin>createuser -s postgres

createuser: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "cdeguide" does not exist

 

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin>createuser -s cdeguide

createuser: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "cdeguide" does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Start the cluster in single-user mode and query `pg_authid` for the bootstrap superuser:

```
SELECT rolname FROM pg_authid WHERE oid = 10
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Lorentz. I tried to start the cluster in single-user mode by the command C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin>postgres --single -O -D $PGDATA $DB_NAME but it gives the error Execution of PostgreSQL by a user with administrative permissions is not permitted. The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent possible system security compromises.  See the documentation for more information on how to properly start the server. I suppose I must not be administrator of the CMD tool, is that right ?

Comment: I will see on monday morning

Comment: Correct, use a different operating system user.